# Could Someone Please Help me to Identify What Type of Squash This One Is?

Tags: squash

[image]

So I can try and plan out some recipes using it..
Thanks in advance!
:D

Comment: Hi Jenna! Can you give us some sense of scale for your squash? How long is it? What's the diameter? It might help to know where you are, too. Some types of squash are more typical in some parts of the world than others.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly! And yes, I’m in Portland Oregon and I grew these in my garden and just picked a few within the last week or two(the ones pictured here) but I can’t remember for the life of me what they are exactly. And one of the squash is approximately 9 1/2 inches long and  approx. 12” around the fattest part of the squash. Also I’m completely guesstimating (cuz my kitchen scale is reading “overload”) but I think they are close to 34 oz. Around there. Thank you, again, in advance!

Comment: Also keep in mind that Squash, Pumpkin, Melon and zucchini are really prone to crossbreed and there are about a million variations. Just make sure when you don´t take seeds from anything not pollinated under controlled conditions - decorative gourds can mix in and make the offspring poisonous.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a Cocozelle Green Striped Summer Squash, a type of zucchini.

Comment: Yes, so ultimately test the texture of it and use in basically any zucchini application...